# Stencil with RxJS 6

Tags: rxjs6, stenciljs

I faced a problem using stencil with rxjs 6

Just created a stencil component by executing `npm init stencil` and chose `component` from the list.

Added `rxjs` to `package.json` and updated stencil to latest version:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@stencil/core": "^0.18.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0"
  }
```

Created a simple component:

```
import { Component, Element } from '@stencil/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Element() el: HTMLElement;

  componenDidLoad() {
    const btn = this.el.shadowRoot.getElementById('btn');
    const clicks = fromEvent(btn, 'click');
    const result = clicks.pipe(throttleTime(1000));
    result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
  }
  render() {
    return <button id="btn">click me</button>;
  }
}
```

and on `npm run start` got an empty page with following error in the browser console:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'h' of undefined`

[image]

Comment: just replaced `--dev` flag in package.json in `start` script with `--debug` and it started working... ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Did you already created an [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/new) @stenciljs?

Comment: @StefanN yes, there is already an open issue, here: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1328#issuecomment-467848424

Comment: Cool. I hope it'll be picked up soon.

Comment: As far as I saw it will be fixed in stencil@1.0.0 version but it's still in alpha state https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stencil/core?activeTab=versions

Comment: As far as I know, they're currently testing 1.0.0alpha intensively and go to beta soon.

Answer (score 0):

this issue is solved in @stencil/core@1.0.0-beta.1